# vuetify table page is not working and reset back to 1

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuetify.js

I have implemented v-data-table by vuetify.

Everything is doing good until I make a search bar and search from the server. E.g I am at 2nd page and I use the search function and there is only one result but vuetify table remain at 2nd page and show me the searched result.

I would want the page to reset to 1st page.

```
<v-data-table
   :headers="headers"
   :items="users"
   :options.sync="options"
   :server-items-length="pagination.total"
   class="elevation-1"
   :footer-props="{
     itemsPerPageOptions: [10],
   }"
 >

searchUser() {
  this.options.page = 1;
  this.pagination.current = 1;
  this.pagination.page = 1;

  this.fetchItems();
  // this.$nextTick().then(()=>{
  //   this.$set(this.pagination, 'page', 1);
  //   this.$set(this.pagination, 'current', 1);
  //   this.$set(this.options, 'page', 1);
  // });
},
```

I tried to change the page value once I run the search function but still no luck for me. Please Help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vuetify recently updated their docs and live version to 2.0, but you still might be using the stable 1.5 release.

If you're using **Vuetify 1.5**, here's the [documentation](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-table). It says you have to use a synchronized `pagination` prop:

> Pagination can be controlled externally by using the `pagination` prop.
>   Remember that you must apply the `.sync` modifier.

Here is the template code. I didn't really understand why you needed to have two locations to store the current page number, so I ignored your `pagination.page` and used `pagination.current` as the main indicator:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="users"
  :pagination.sync="pagination.current"
  class="elevation-1"
>
```

And if you're using **Vuetify 2.0**, here's the [latest documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables). It says you can choose between setting an individual prop or change an attribute inside the `options` prop. Both ways require the `.sync` modifier:

> Pagination can be controlled externally by using the individual props,
>   or by using the `options` prop. Remember that you must apply the `.sync`
>   modifier.

However I couldn't find much details about the `options` prop, so I based the sample code below on the individual `page` prop:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="users"
  :page.sync="pagination.current"
  :server-items-length="pagination.total"
  class="elevation-1"
  :footer-props="{
    itemsPerPageOptions: [10],
  }"
>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Trying the options.sync for page syncing from serverside, this seems not working and has an open issue in vuetify data tables as well. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14757